# flex DateChooser needs to not be selectable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm sure this is pretty easy but I'm at a loss with this one.  I have a DateChooser that I'm using to highlight dates when things are being released.  And that's all I want it for.  I want to turn off the ability for users to click on anything.  I don't see how to have selectable false.  Anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two properties that you can use to turn off user interaction:

- First is the **enabled** property, set it `enabled="false"` in mxml and user
  interaction will be disabled. However, Flex will render the
  DateChooser dim (kind of faded away).

  <mx:DateChooser id="date1" enabled="false" />
- Another option is the **mouseChildren** property, if you set it to
  `mouseChildren="false"` as well all children of the display object will not be enabled, in the case of the **DateChooser** it disables all user interaction too.

  <mx:DateChooser id="date1" mouseChildren="false" />

Comment: Thanks danii -- I actually tried the enabled="false" yesterday but I was getting some funkiness with the dates being shown as selected.  The mouseChildren seems to be working just fine, thanks for the responses from everyone!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help... I always expect some kind of "funkiness" when using the enabled, mouseEnabled and mouseChildren properties so I end up trying different combinations until I find one that works for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try placing it behind a Group that has a fill with alfa 0.  That way the group will take the clicks and do nothing with them.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, then you could use the *disabledDays*, *disabledRange* or *selectableRange* properties of the *DateChooser*. E.g. such as in the code from the [adobe website](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_12.html):

```
  <mx:DateChooser 
   selectableRange="{{rangeStart: new Date(2006,0,1),
    rangeEnd: new Date(2006,2,15)}}"
   disabledRanges="{[new Date(2006,0,11), 
    {rangeStart: new Date(2006,0,23), rangeEnd: new Date(2006,1,10)}]}"
   disabledDays="{[0,6]}"/>
```

Use this to disable all other dates than the one(s) you want highlighted. I was actually just wondering if i should do something similar, but I just ended opp using a disabled *DateField*(enabled=false) to display the date. I hope this helps :)